# What should I put in requirements.txt to install this library from github?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, py-telegram-bot-api

This library: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

I know I need to use format like the following:

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==X.X.X
```

However it's not obvious from the github page what to replace `X.X.X` with.

Comment: 0.3.0 is the latest version on pypi https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/

Comment: Although you can not pass a specific version at all and get the latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Installation from git

If you want to install from git, use

```
git+https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI.git
```

### Installation from PyPI

If you just want to install the latest version from PyPI, just use

```
pyTelegramBotAPI
```

or if you want to install a minimum version:

```
pyTelegramBotAPI>=3.0.0
```

Comment: Ok, but this command `$ pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` is recommended on github's readme. So pip should understand where to take that lib without specifying the github link?

Comment: How should pip know where to take it from?

Comment: It does? When I just run `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` from command line, it does download and install that library. So it somehow does know where to take it from.

Comment: pip installs by default from pypi. If you want to install from github as stated in the title of the question, you have to provide a link to github.